# How to LOOP inside the Array returned from jQuery Ajax Success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to loop the returning Array from `PHP`. But still don't get the way. Examples are ~

PHP:

```
$items = array();
$items["country"] = "North Korea",
$items["fruits"] = array(
                      "apple"=>1.0,
                      "banana"=>1.2,
                      "cranberry"=>2.0,
                    );
echo json_encode( $fruits );
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "items.php",
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "command" : "getItems" }
}).success(function( response ) {

    alert( response.fruits.apple ); //OK
    // <------ here, how do i loop the response.fruits ? -----

});
```

Then how can i loop to know which Fruits i got, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
$.each(response.fruits,function(key,value){

console.log(key+":"+value);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to achieve what you want.

Try,

```
$.each(response.fruits,function(key,val){
   alert(key);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over the properties of an object like

```
$.each(response.fruits, function(key,val){
    console.log(key + '-' + val)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

All these examples uses `jQuery`, but you can do it with native `ECMA5` [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). No library needed!

```
response.fruits.forEach(function(value){
    //do what you need to do
});
```